sjasmplus. Way to have a placeholder for assembly code within a macro
started to use sjasmplus assembler for z80 experiments. I'm novice to both assembly programming and to sjasmplus.
Question:
is there any way to achieve the following - I want to have a reusable code, that would work like below. Imagine an arg2 that is indeed a block of my provided assembly code:
SMTH_LIKE_MACRO FN_A arg1, arg2
    LD A, arg1
    ... some logic

    [arg2]  <-- placeholder, it inserts my provided block of asm ops kept in arg2

    ... some logic
    LD B, arg1

ENDM
     

Mental model for what I want to achieve in higher level languages like: function FN_A is eating a function FN_B as an argument arg2 (higher order functions).
Thank you.
